# Plotting stacked bars with a total line and dates on xlabels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am using the pandas plot to generate a stacked bar chart, which has a different behaviour from matplotlib's, but the dates always come out with a bad format and I could not change it.
I would also like to a "total" line on the chart. But when I try to add it, the previous bars are erased.
I want to make a chart like the one below (generated by excel). The black line is the sum of the bars.

[image]

I've looked at some solutions online, but they only look good when there are not many bars, so you get some space between the labels.

Here is the best I could do and below there is the code I used.

[image]

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker

# DATA (not the full series from the chart)
dates = ['2016-10-31', '2016-11-30', '2016-12-31', '2017-01-31', '2017-02-28', '2017-03-31',
         '2017-04-30', '2017-05-31', '2017-06-30', '2017-07-31', '2017-08-31', '2017-09-30',
         '2017-10-31', '2017-11-30', '2017-12-31', '2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31',
         '2018-04-30', '2018-05-31', '2018-06-30', '2018-07-31', '2018-08-31', '2018-09-30',
         '2018-10-31', '2018-11-30', '2018-12-31', '2019-01-31', '2019-02-28', '2019-03-31']

variables = {'quantum ex sa': [6.878011, 6.557054, 3.229360, 3.739318, 1.006442, -0.117945,
                               -1.854614, -2.882032, -1.305225, 0.280100, 0.524068, 1.847649,
                               5.315940, 4.746596, 6.650303, 6.809901, 8.135243, 8.127328,
                               9.202209, 8.146417, 6.600906, 6.231881, 5.265775, 3.971435,
                               2.896829, 4.307549, 4.695687, 4.696656, 3.747793, 3.366878],
             'price ex sa': [-11.618681, -9.062433, -6.228452, -2.944336, 0.513788, 4.068517,
                             6.973203, 8.667524, 10.091766, 10.927501, 11.124805, 11.368854,
                             11.582204, 10.818471, 10.132152, 8.638781, 6.984159, 5.161404,
                             3.944813, 3.723371, 3.808564, 4.576303, 5.170760, 5.237303,
                             5.121998, 5.502981, 5.159970, 4.772495, 4.140812, 3.568077]}

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.to_datetime(dates), data=variables)

# PLOTTING
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, width=1)
# df['Total'] = df.sum(axis=1)
# df['Total'].plot(ax=ax)
ax.axhline(0, linewidth=1)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plticker.PercentFormatter())

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

## Edit

This is what work best for me. This works better than using the pandas `df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)` because it allows for better formatting of the date labels in the x axis and also allows for any number of series for the bars.

```py
    for count, col in enumerate(df.columns):
        old = df.iloc[:, :count].sum(axis=1)
        bottom_series = ((old >= 0) == (df[col] >= 0)) * old

        ax.bar(df.index, df[col], label=col, bottom=bottom_series, width=31)

    df['Total'] = df.sum(axis=1)
    ax.plot(df.index, df['Total'], color='black', label='Total')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(16,9))
# PLOTTING
ax.bar(df.index, df['price ex sa'], bottom=df['quantum ex sa'],width=31, label='price ex sa')
ax.bar(df.index, df['quantum ex sa'], width=31, label='quantum ex sa')

total = df.sum(axis=1)
ax.plot(total.index, total, color='r', linewidth=3, label='total')

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Edit: There seems to be a bug (features) on plotting with datetime. I tried to convert the index to string and it works:

```
df.index=df.index.strftime('%Y-%m')

ax = df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, width=1)
df['Total'] = df.sum(axis=1)
df['Total'].plot(ax=ax, label='total')
ax.legend()
```

[image]

---

Edit 2: I think I know what's going on. The problem is that

```
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

returns/sets x-axis of `ax` to `range(len(df))` labeled by the corresponding values from `df.index`, but not `df.index` itself. That's why if we plot the second series on the same `ax`, it doesn't show (due to different scale of xaxis). So I tried:

```
# PLOTTING
colums = df.columns

ax = df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, width=1, figsize=(10, 6))
ax.plot(range(len(df)), df.sum(1), label='Total')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

and it works as expected

[image]

Comment: That is a solution for this case, where there are only two series. Is there a way to generalize so that I could have any number of series for the bars?

Comment: @GustavoAmarante see edit for a go-around. I may have a better trick coming up.

Comment: Yeah, I got that too. But your first answer gave me an idea. Let me try it and I'll post it here if ti works.

Comment: I ended up going with another solution, but it was inspired on your first answer. Thank you for your help.