# Plotting barplot and line from pandas dataframe with different y axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe I want to plot. I'm trying to have 2 subplots, one of them with two plots on it (with different y axes and sharing the x)

```
size = (20,10)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=size)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax3 = ax2.twinx()

# the dataframe is obtained by other means, and has the following format:

Date        col1        col2    col3    col4        
2017-06-30  7813.9291   0.0000  0.0000  0.000000
2017-07-31  8222.1428   0.0000  0.0000  4.964809
2017-08-31  7010.1959   0.0000  0.0000  -17.288346
2017-09-30  5878.8063   0.0000  0.0000  -19.245227
.
.
.

df.iloc[:,0:3].plot.bar(figsize = size, ax = ax3)
df.iloc[:,-1].plot(figsize = size, ax = ax2)
```

The other plot with only one plot in the figure(in ax1) does not give any problems, so I won't post it here.

The problem is, when I run this code, only one the plots remains in the figure, (the last line), and the other just disappears. If I switch the order of the last two lines, then the other plot remains.

Any ideas why is this happening?

EDIT: I'm using a jupyter notebook, with pandas 0.24 and python 3.7

Comment: I don't understand the problem. It works fine for me. The last plot is correct: There is a bar chart and a line. What else do you expect? `col2` is zero so you don't see any bars for `col2`. The only bars will come from `col1`

Comment: My problem is that I either see the barplot or the line, _but not both at the same time_. I'm using a jupyter notebook, last version of pandas and python 3.7

Comment: Strange. It works fine for me in 3.6.5 python, pandas 0.23.0

Comment: Try the following: `df.iloc[:,0:3].plot.bar(ax=ax2, secondary_y=True)` and then `df.iloc[:,-1].plot(ax=ax2)`

Comment: Is your data frame indexed by `Date`?

Comment: Didn't work with @Sheldore solution, and yes, it is indexed by  `Date`, wich is a Datetime index

Comment: Try `df = df.reset_index()` and then re-run your original plotting lines OR the ones I suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```
df.iloc[:,0:3].plot.bar(figsize = size, ax = ax3)
```

sets `ax3.xticks` to `0, 1, ..., len(df)-1` while

```
df.iloc[:,-1].plot(figsize = size, ax = ax2)
```

uses `df.index`, in this case (I guess) the timestamp, which are very very large integers. That's why you don't get to see one of the two plots. Suggestion is to re-do the line plot:

```
df.iloc[:,0:3].plot.bar(figsize = size, ax = ax3)
ax2.plot(range(len(df)), df.iloc[:,-1])
```

You can try some other approaches in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56028578/plotting-stacked-bars-with-a-total-line-and-dates-on-xlabels/56029104#56029104).